# module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'coroutine' on snakemake

Tags: python, python-asyncio, snakemake

I followed the following code to install `snakemake` on my linux machine :

```
conda activate base
mamba create -c conda-forge -c bioconda -n snakemake snakemake
conda activate snakemake
```

Everything was fine, but when I try to run the following code :

```
snakemake -s Snakemake_job -j n
```

I get this error :

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/debian/.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 747, in snakemake
    success = workflow.execute(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/debian/.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 949, in execute
    self.scheduler = JobScheduler(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/debian/.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/snakemake/scheduler.py", line 109, in __init__
    from ratelimiter import RateLimiter
  File "/home/debian/.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ratelimiter.py", line 36, in <module>
    class RateLimiter(object):
  File "/home/debian/.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ratelimiter.py", line 127, in RateLimiter
    __aexit__ = asyncio.coroutine(__exit__)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'coroutine'
```

Does someone have an idea of what is going on? I tried to re-install snakemake, or to pip install asyncio without sucess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoth [the docs for `asyncio.coroutine`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.coroutine), emphasis mine:

> Deprecated since version 3.8, **will be removed in version 3.11**: Use async def instead.

The `ratelimiter` dependency `snakemake` uses is evidently not compatible with Python 3.11.

That package has had [an issue](https://github.com/RazerM/ratelimiter/issues/10) open about this for multiple years, and [`snakemake` seems to be switching dependencies](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/pull/1958).

In other words, your choices are:

- downgrade to Python 3.10 so `ratelimiter` works
- upgrade to a newer version of `snakemake` that doesn't use `ratelimiter`: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/pull/1950

Comment: Do you know what should I do then ?

Comment: Sure, I edited your options into the post.